# 1) I want to auto update a field value by client ID. 2) Also want to update a value in a field in a table when someone creates new record in another

Tags: autonumber

Please be kind. I am retired and new to Access. I am helping a friend set up a simple(ish) database for their charity, and while I can manage the simpler stuff, I have run into a couple of problems.
I have a Client Master table- keyed on Client ID (autonumber). I also have a Client sessions table - keyed on Client ID and Session ID.
If I make the Session ID auto number then it increments regardless of the Client, but I want it to increment within each Client. How do I do that please?

Secondly - Each client can have multiple care packages, each consisting of 5 sessions. These need to be set up on the table Care Packages Master, where there is a field "Sessions used". When someone adds a record to the Sessions ID file using a form with subform that I have created I want the "Sessions used" field to be incremented by 1, and return an error if the 5 sessions have already been used.

Thanks for any help given to a beginner.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for replying, and sorry for the late response. The first problem I think I've resolved, but regarding the 2nd. I'd like to include some screenshots but I can't see how to attach or copy/paste them. Any advice?